# C++ call by reference or not /?

Tags: c++

Which one of those two methods should i use?

```
int Foo= XXX::instance().yyy(NULL);
```

OR

```
auto &q = XXX::instance();
int Foo = q.yyy(NULL);
```

Comment: Both are the same, just a matter of taste (I suspect `instance()` return a `&`).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Well, the 2nd form would make it easier to factor out the _Singleton_ in a future iteration when going over the code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's true. Still opinion based IMHO.

Comment: There's no "call by reference" here.

Comment: The most important thing about writing code is that the target audience is your future self and other programmers.  People will read the code far more than write the code.  To that end, writing for legibility is foremost, and trusting that your compiler's optimizer will do a fabulous job will help you sleep at night.  Since the second example is more easily understood by a reader of the code, that's the version I'd recommend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the form

```
auto &q = XXX::instance();
int Foo = q.yyy(NULL);
```

has at least two clear advantages:

1. It's shorter to write `q.foo()`, instead of having to write `XXX::instance().foo()` everywhere you need the instance
2. Supposed that `XXX` is a *Singleton*, and that's generally considered a bad design (because you have a direct coupling to `XXX`), that form would make it way easier to refactor the code later, as soon you want to replace `XXX` with a more generic interface.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
auto &q = XXX::instance();
int Foo = q.yyy(NULL);
```

for the following reasons:

- You can inspect the variable when you are debugging more easily
- Entering the function with your debugger becomes more clear in some IDEs
- Scrolling vertically is easier on most devices
- The compiler will optimize it for you
- If you add further calls you can just use `q.` instead of repeating yourself.